# I don't have a round timer on TF2?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I've been playing TF2, and have realised that my game doesn't have a timer like some other peoples. I asked another player playing on my server and they had a timer (in the top of the screen).

How do I reenable to the timer? (And any other regular HUD features...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options delete the hud folder and that should recreate itself back to the default hud. 
Or you can install a new hud there are many

http://teamfortress.tv/forum/thread/183-collection-of-custom-huds

there is a thread with a collection of huds. Its preference if you wish to use that.

else what you can try in game is a command in the console called

```
hud_reloadscheme
```

which will reload all hud elements but this may not fix the issue.

Comment: Another thing you can add to this answer would be to ensure there are no mods in the custom folder interfering with the HUD.

Comment: All I had to do in the end was restart my computer... Not entirely sure how it helped, and I'm all for the don't reboot, debug approach. I'm sure this would have worked though. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

What I did was just play the training mode for the Soldier (specifically the 2nd Half of it) then after I finished it my timer showed up --- (This may work of all the time I guess)